# uwp store submission with error - image files missing from package

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2017, assets

I have several apps that i've been developing over the years. Suddenly when trying to update those apps in the store i'm getting the below errors (list is much larger) that the image assets are missing. I've tried everything that came to mind. Deleting all assets.

Generating them new with Visual studios Generator, placing them manually in the asset editor, changing the path and as well generating them with another plugin available for VS2017 (Version 15.5.5) that I'm using. It passes the local WACK but when uploading it to the store it gives me those errors even though all the files are there.

The same happens when compiling the package on another computer (with the same VS2017 version though).

[image]

**Update1:**

content of manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="xxx" Publisher="CN=17BADF30-AB0D-4280-xxxxxxxxx" Version="1.6.31.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="c4efa60d-49b3-41fc-8532-b0a3cf9add1f" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>xxxxx</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>xxxxx</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\Store\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="xxxxxx.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="xxxxxx" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Medium\Medium150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\AppList\AppList.png" Description="Chatterboks" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:LockScreen Notification="badgeAndTileText" BadgeLogo="Assets\Badge\Badge.png" />
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide\Wide310x150Logo.png" ShortName="Chatterboks" Square310x310Logo="Assets\Large\Large310x310Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Small\Small71x71Logo.png">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo" />
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="white" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
        <uap:Rule Match="https://xxxx.com" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
      </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>
      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap:Protocol Name="thisisonlyforxxxxx">
            <uap:Logo>Assests\Logo.png</uap:Logo>
          </uap:Protocol>
        </uap:Extension>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.shareTarget">
          <uap:ShareTarget Description="Send content to xxxx">
            <uap:DataFormat>Text</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>URI</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>HTML</uap:DataFormat>
            <uap:DataFormat>RTF</uap:DataFormat>
          </uap:ShareTarget>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="contacts" />
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

[image]

Comment: its seems like when you upload or compile it generated a code am i right? Now it is very clear that the path of your file is not exists.

Comment: Make sure the images have the build action of Content and are set to Copy Always

Comment: @VijunavVastivch the local WACK doesn't give a problem and i can run the app locally. only after uploading it to the store it gives me the error in certification.

Comment: @MartinZikmund I'll try that now. It's just weird that if it's the "copy always" that the assets generator doesn't set it to that.

Comment: What is this mean `error in certification`. You mean is, this is not all about images?

Comment: @VijunavVastivch I'm talking about the certification of microsoft in the store. After uploading your package to the store it goes through 3 steps: Pre-processing, certification and publishing. During the certification it gets stopped with the errors i'm describing above.

Comment: The file you wish to upload is a published file from your project? Did you try to look over your package how is it look like? if the images are included. The path is right? or maybe you need to update the path generated before uploading?

Comment: @VijunavVastivch - Yes, all that i explained above. It's a UWP app. It can only be published when it's compiled in a certain way and only after it passes the local WACK. I just published another package after the tip of Martin Zikmund . I'll get back if it passes certification now in the store.

Comment: It is very weird it passes the local WACK. I am afraid my suggestion will not help, but better try anything...

Comment: @MartinZikmund same outcome unfortunately. Doesn't pass certification in the store.

Comment: The validation and compilation passes on the other computer as well?

Comment: @MartinZikmund Yes. Everything passes. Only when uploaded to the store it doesn't. Makes me think it's a VS issue cause before i had a similar issue, but then when i compiled it on a different computer with a different VS version it worked. Might look to install an older version. And of course microsoft only will help if you pay their 500USD for a one time help ticket.

Comment: A few more suggestions: 1) try creating a new blank app with the image files you are using and submit it as to store under a new name, just to see if ti passes. 2) make sure your Assets folder doesn't mix images with `scale` suffix and with simple name (like "StoreLogo.png" and "StoreLogo.scale-200.png") this might confuse the certification somehow. 3) try to open run the images through a image editor to make sure they are not corrupted somehow. Also ensure the images are smaller than 200 KB. 4) Try to submit the app once with simple asset names only (like StoreLogo.png).

Comment: Also please to post the relevant parts of your `csproj` file and please post the the whole `Package.appxmanifest` file contents (as XML file, of course you can omit app name and app IDs and other sensitive info) and a screenshot of the expanded `Assets` folder in Visual Studio Solution Explorer. We will solve this :-) !

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thanks. I will do so. Currently I downloaded VS2017 preview (15.5.6 i believe) and compiled it with that. It's currently in certification and I'll keep you posted if it'll go through or not.

Comment: Please post the appxmanifest contents as soon as possible :-)

Comment: @MartinZikmund compiling and uploading it to the store from VS Preview resulted with the same error. i updated the answer to include the manifest. As well as an example of the folder structure.

Comment: @MartinZikmund did you have a chance to look over it? Still getting the same problem.

Comment: During the app package creation, have you checked the create bundle checkbox in the dialog?

Comment: @MartinZikmund yeah, create app bundle is set to always

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when deleting an Image from Project Directory manually it could cause an error mostly if those images are included at your build or compiled/compilation.

Now the solution is:

In your Project Solution Explorer, `Delete or exclude` the images that cause an error then restore the images you wanted to include to your Project. Then run compile.

Include the images only that is used by your project. Otherwise exclude.

Comment: tried it all. deleted it through the solutions explorer and added it there as well. As well i tried adding it again through the assets editor and the other things i described unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue many times and this is how I fix it :

- Close VS
- Delete obj folder in your project
- Open your project
- Clean it
- Rebuild it
- Create a new app bundle

Sometimes the issue isn't fix but after few tries it finally works well...